# HTMLLoader: Navigate Back and Forward in Page History

Tags: flash, air

I never had problems navigating Back and Forward through page history of Htmlloader that was a child of the main Native Window stage. I just have to use: HtmlLoaderVariable.historyForward();

But when i add HTMLLoader as a child to a new Native Window, it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
function createNewHtmlWindow(pageUrl:String):void{
    //Everytime I click a button, this function creates a seperate Native Window each containing HtmlLoader Class to load a webpage

    var myhtml= new HTMLLoader();
    myhtml.width = 1000;
    myhtml.height = 780;    
    myhtml.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myHtmlLoaded);


    var myHtmloptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
    myHtmloptions.transparent = false;
    myHtmloptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
    myHtmloptions.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;   

    var extHtmlWindow = new NativeWindow(myHtmloptions);    
    extHtmlWindow.title="new title";
    extHtmlWindow.width = 1015;
    extHtmlWindow.height = 800; 

    extHtmlWindow.activate();
    extHtmlWindow.stage.align = "TL";
    extHtmlWindow.stage.scaleMode = "noScale"; 
    extHtmlWindow.stage.addChild(myhtml);

    var backNativeWin=new BackButton();
    backNativeWin.x=5;
    backNativeWin.y=500;
    backNativeWin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadPrevHistory);
    extHtmlWindow.stage.addChild(backNativeWin);

    var nextNativeWin=new NextButton();
    nextNativeWin.x=30;
    nextNativeWin.y=500;    
    nextNativeWin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadNextHistory);
    extHtmlWindow.stage.addChild(nextNativeWin);

    myhtml.load(new URLRequest(pageUrl));
}

function myHtmlLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    //Page loads successfully

}


function loadNextHistory(m:MouseEvent):void{
    output.text="Next>>"+m.target.parent.getChildAt(0); //Next>>[object HTMLLoader] 
    m.target.parent.getChildAt(0).historyForward(); // This line is not working


}

function loadPrevHistory(m:MouseEvent):void{
    output.text="Prev>>"+m.target.parent.getChildAt(0); //Prev>>[object HTMLLoader]
    m.target.parent.getChildAt(0).historyBack(); // This line is not working

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what is causing issues, but you should avoid ever using the `parent` property to run a command. You never want to traverse backwards up the display list (or any object tree in OOP languages), only forwards. The only time the `parent` property should ever be used is for checking if the parent exists or what the data type of the parent is. You should save references to the things you need as properties of an available object instead.

Comment: You are right Josh. I got it working just by referencing the parent as a property, and then used getChildAt(0). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code with my own web page, it works perfectly well..
here's my code:

```
import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
import org.aswing.JButton;
import flash.filesystem.File;

function createNewHtmlWindow(pageUrl:String):void{
//Everytime I click a button, this function creates a seperate Native Window each containing HtmlLoader Class to load a webpage

var myhtml= new HTMLLoader();
myhtml.width = 1000;
myhtml.height = 680;    
myhtml.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myHtmlLoaded);


var myHtmloptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
myHtmloptions.transparent = false;
myHtmloptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
myHtmloptions.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;   

var extHtmlWindow = new NativeWindow(myHtmloptions);    
extHtmlWindow.title="new title";
extHtmlWindow.width = 1015;
extHtmlWindow.height = 700; 

extHtmlWindow.activate();
extHtmlWindow.stage.align = "TL";
extHtmlWindow.stage.scaleMode = "noScale"; 
extHtmlWindow.stage.addChild(myhtml);

var backNativeWin:JButton=new JButton("back");
backNativeWin.setSizeWH(100,22);
backNativeWin.x=5;
backNativeWin.y=500;
backNativeWin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadPrevHistory);
extHtmlWindow.stage.addChild(backNativeWin);

var nextNativeWin=new JButton("next");
nextNativeWin.setSizeWH(100,22);
nextNativeWin.x=130;
nextNativeWin.y=500;    
nextNativeWin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadNextHistory);
extHtmlWindow.stage.addChild(nextNativeWin);

myhtml.load(new URLRequest(pageUrl));
}

function myHtmlLoaded(e:Event):void{
//Page loads successfully
}


function loadNextHistory(m:MouseEvent):void{
trace("Next>>"+m.target.parent.getChildAt(0)); //Next>>[object HTMLLoader] 
m.target.parent.getChildAt(0).historyForward(); // This line is not working
}

function loadPrevHistory(m:MouseEvent):void{
trace("Prev>>"+m.target.parent.getChildAt(0)); //Prev>>[object HTMLLoader]
m.target.parent.getChildAt(0).historyBack(); // This line is not working

}
createNewHtmlWindow(File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("index.html").url);
```

And here's index.html on my desktop:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Click me to jump to Google.</a>
</body>
```

So I think there must be something wrong with your test website, changing for another to try again may help..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the website. Its just the referencing of  parent.getChildAt(0) that caused problem. It has to be referenced as a property. Now its working